# If $Z^TWZ$ is positive defiite, $\overline{Z} = (Z, u)$, prove $\overline{Z}^TW\overline{Z}$ is positive semidefinite.

Tags: linear-algebra

Here $W$ is a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix, $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times l}$(as mentioned in @stewbasic's comment, here $n$ probably should be $\leq l$), $u\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\overline{Z} = (Z, u)$. I need to prove if $Z^TWZ$ is positive definite, then $\overline{Z}^TW\overline{Z}$ is positive semidefinite.

To prove $\overline{Z}^TW\overline{Z}$ is positive semidefinite, I need to show $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^l$, $\forall y\in\mathbb{R}$,

$$
\begin{align}
\left(x^T,y\right)\overline{Z}^TW\overline{Z}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} & = \left(x^T,y\right)\begin{pmatrix}Z^TWZ & Z^TWu\\u^TWZ & u^TWu\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\\
    & = x^TZ^TWZx + 2y\cdot x^TZ^TWu + y^2\cdot u^TWu\\
    & \geq 0
\end{align}
$$

It is clear that, as $Z^TWZ$ is positive definite, $x^TZ^TWZx > 0$, but I do not have any idea how to deal with $x^TZ^TWu$ and $u^TWu$.

Is there any way to prove $x^TZ^TWu$ and $u^TWu$ are greater or equal than $x^TZ^TWZx$, so that I can get $\left(y+1\right)^2x^TZ^TWZx \geq 0$ ?

Comment: Isn't this false if $Z=({1\atop 0})$, $u=({0\atop1})$ and $W=\mathrm{diag}(1,-1)$?

Comment: I think it's true if you are given $n\leq l$.

Comment: @stewbasic Thank you for your comment. You are right, there is something wrong with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement may be false if $n>l$; for example consider $Z=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$, $u=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $W=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$. So suppose $n\leq l$. Actually this forces $n=l$ as shown below...

---

Since $Z^TWZ$ is positive definite, it is nonsingular. Hence
$$
  n\leq l=\mathrm{rk}(Z^TWZ)\leq\mathrm{rk}(Z)\leq n.
$$
Thus $n=l$ and $Z$ is nonsingular. Therefore $u=Zv$ for some $v\in\mathbb R^n$. Now
$$
  \overline Z\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=Zx+yu=Z(x+yv),
$$
so
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}x^T&y\end{pmatrix}\overline Z^TW
  \overline Z\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}
    =(x+yv)^TZ^TWZ(x+yv)\geq0.
$$

Comment: Thank you, your answer helps a lot. There is a typo in the last line of your answer, $(x+yv)^TW(x+yv)\geq0$ should be $(x+yv)^TZ^TWZ(x+yv)\geq0$.

Comment: @will fixed, thanks.